# What does "never mind" really mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

What does "never mind" really mean?

I am trying to find out the answer for it. I have been hearing that for years, but I don't use it myself because I do NOT know the true meaning.

Comment: If its a matter of specific usage, you should add a phrase or phrases using "never mind", based on your understanding or what you heard. Then we could address a specific meaning. As it is you are just asking about the meaning which can be found in a dictionary.

Answer (score 13):

It means *do not think about (something)* and is used in a variety of contexts:

- Have you seen my glasses? ... oh, never mind. I found them.  = *Give it no more thought*
- Never mind, I know you didn't mean to do it. = *Don't worry about it*
- Never mind what ***she*** says, do what ***I*** say.  = *Pay no attention to it*
- I can't even run around the block, never mind a marathon. = *To say nothing of*

You may find even more uses in the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/never+mind#mind_2). Phrases of this sort are usually listed in good dictionaries, after the definitions of the headword.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use it sometimes when trying to talk to someone but it gets so frustrating I give up.  For instance:

I might say "The sky is blue."

They might say "Not really.  It only appears blue because ...."

I'd reply "Never mind"

Answer (score -2):

To me, it usually means *forget about it* or *don't worry about it*.